# How to add routes for a new template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new in Ruby and Rails and little bit confused about rendering and adding routes for a new template.

I have following `link_to` tag

```
<td colspan="3">
 <%= link_to 'Show Current State', simulation, :action => :current_state, :class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
</td>
```

Where `simulation` is the name of controller and action is name of the method in `SimulationController`.

I added this in my `routes.rb`

```
  resources :simulations, except: [:edit]

  resources :simulations do
    collection do
     get 'current_state'
     post 'current_state'
   end
 end
```

In my `SimulationController` class I added a new method i.e.

```
  def current_state
   byebug
  end
```

My problem? routes is not re-directing to `current_state` method. Instead, it is redirecting to `http://localhost:3000/simulations/{someID}`

This redirection is calling `show` action.

```
def show
 ...
end
```

How can I make this work out and make `<%= @simulation.dat %>` line accessible in `new.html.erb`. Location of `new.html.erb` is in following path

```
views/simulations/index.html.js
views/similations/show.html.js
views/simulations/new.html.erb
```

This could be a basic question but I am new to rails 4. Thanks in advance.

## Edit-1

Def of `get_state` method in `controller`

```
 def get_state
  @simulation = current_user.simulations.find(params[:id])
  return not_found if @simulation.nil?  
  .....
  /// How to send `@simulation` into `state.html.erb` formally as `new.html.erb`
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have too many misses in your code.

First, You don't need 2 `resources :simulations`, just merge them into one:

```
resources :simulations, except: :edit do
  member do
    get 'current_state', action: 'get_state'
    post 'current_state', action: 'change_state'
  end
end
```

Note that the original `collection` block is changed to a `member` block.
The difference between a `collection` block and a `member` block is that you need to provide an **resource id** for each routes in the `member` block, while no resource id is required for those in the `collection` block.

Also note that I added `action: 'xxx'` in each route, so you have to add these 2 actions in your `SimulationsController`, one for GET requests, and the other for POST requests.

### UPDATE

In both of these actions, add `render 'new'` at the end.

### END OF UPDATE

Run `rake routes` in your console (or `bundle exec rake routes` if you have multiple versions of rails installed), and you will see all the routes along with there url helper methods listed, like this:

```
                   Prefix Verb URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
current_state_simulations GET  /simulations/:id/current_state simulations#get_state
current_state_simulations POST /simulations/:id/current_state simulations#change_state
...
```

According to the **Prefix** column, the link in the view should be

```
<%= link_to 'Show Current State', current_state_simulations_path(simulation), :class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
```

Or in short

```
<%= link_to 'Show Current State', [:current_state, simulation], :class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
```

### UPDATE FOR Edit-1

Don't `return` in actions, because `return` doesn't stop rendering.
Instead, use `raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')` to redirect users to the 404 page.

You can define an instance method in `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
  def not_found!
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end
end
```

And modify your `SimulationsController`:

```
def get_state
  @simulation = current_user.simulations.find(params[:id])
  not_found! unless @simulation
  # ...
  render 'new'
end
```

**Best Practice**
For dynamic page web applications, **don't render views for non-GET requests!**

Why? Because if a user POSTs some data to your web app, and then refreshes his/her browser, that request gets POSTed again, and your database got tainted. Same for PATCH, PUT and DELETE requests.

You can **redirect** the user to a GET path if the non-GET request succeeds, or to a 400 page if the non-GET request fails.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation but you haven't tell me about how to render `new.html.erb` from `get_state` method defined in `controller` class. I can see the debug point is coming into `get_state` now

Comment: I think it's not updated yet . could you please confirm it?

Comment: Sorry for not emphasising the update. Updated again.